# Div goes to wrong position

Tags: javascript, css

I am editing the vertical slider I used from [this color picker](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker). It uses `top` to adjust the cursors position. I want to use `transform translateY` instead. When I do that, I apparently have to calculate it differently.

The original calculation is: ([Line: #286](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/index.js#L286))

```
hsv_barcursor.style.top = ((1 - color.hsv.v) * hsv_barHeight) + 'px';
```

My updated version is: (Line 43 at JSFiddle Below)

```
hsv_barcursor.style.transform = 'translateY(calc(' + (color.RND.hsv.v * 10) + '% - ' + cursorRadius + 'px))';
```

The position of my version is wrong.

1. Why doesn't the math for `top` work for `tranlateY`?
2. What's the correct math to use for `translateY`?

I'm not looking for JQuery answers, nor am I looking for `html's` input range.

#### JSFiddle

```js
var luminenceBarWrapper = document.getElementById('luminenceBarWrapper'),
  hsv_barBGLayer = document.getElementById('bar-bg'),
  hsv_barcursor = document.getElementById('hsv-barcursor'),
  hsv_barCursors = document.getElementById('hsv-barcursors'),

  hsv_barHeight = hsv_barCursors.offsetHeight,
  cursorRadius = hsv_barcursor.offsetHeight / 2,
  startPoint,
  currentTarget,
  myColor = new Colors();

// Create Event Functions
var hsvDown = function(e) { // mouseDown callback
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target === hsv_barcursor) currentTarget = e.target.parentNode;
    else if (e.target === hsv_barCursors) currentTarget = e.target;
    else return;

    startPoint = getOrigin(currentTarget);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', hsvMove);
    hsvMove(e);
    startRender();
  },
  hsvMove = function(e) { // mouseMove callback
    myColor.setColor({
      v: (hsv_barHeight - (e.clientY - startPoint.top)) / hsv_barHeight * 100
    }, 'hsv');
  };

// Initial Rendering
doRender(myColor.colors);

// Adde Events To Objects
luminenceBarWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', hsvDown);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', hsvMove);
  stopRender();
});

function doRender(color) {
  hsv_barcursor.style.transform = 'translateY(calc(' + (color.RND.hsv.v * 10) + '% - ' + cursorRadius + 'px))';
  //hsv_barcursor.style.top = ((1 - color.hsv.v) * hsv_barHeight) + 'px';
}

var renderTimer,
  startRender = function(oneTime) {
    renderTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
      doRender(myColor.colors);
    }, 13); // 1000 / 60); // ~16.666 -> 60Hz or 60fps
  },
  stopRender = function() {
    window.clearInterval(renderTimer);
  };

function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
}
#bar-bg {
  width: 15px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
#hsv-barcursors {
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.5px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 0;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#hsv-barcursor {
  position: absolute;
  right: 7.5px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/PitPik/colorPicker/master/colors.js"></script>

<div id="luminenceBarWrapper">
  <div id="bar-bg"></div>
  <div id="hsv-barcursors" id="hsv_cursors">
    <div id="hsv-barcursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`translateY(Npx)` translates something downward if `N > 0` therefore you need `translate(0px)` when the marker is up and `translate(Npx)` when the marker is down at the bottom of your component

Your variables are

- `color.RND.hsv.v` which is 100 when the marker is up and 0 when the marker is down
- `hsv_barHeight` is the height of your component

The first step is to invert the value of `color.RND.hsv.v` i.e. `(100 - color.RND.hsv.v)` next we will map it to the range `[0,1]` which is simply done by a simple division i.e. `t = (100 - color.RND.hsv.v) / 100` we do this so that the height is linearly mapped with this value `t` to be in the range `[0, height]` i.e. `(100 - color.RND.hsv.v) / 100 * hsv_barHeight` which is the final equation

```js
var luminenceBarWrapper = document.getElementById('luminenceBarWrapper'),
  hsv_barBGLayer = document.getElementById('bar-bg'),
  hsv_barcursor = document.getElementById('hsv-barcursor'),
  hsv_barCursors = document.getElementById('hsv-barcursors'),

  hsv_barHeight = hsv_barCursors.offsetHeight,
  cursorRadius = hsv_barcursor.offsetHeight / 2,
  startPoint,
  currentTarget,
  myColor = new Colors();

// Create Event Functions
var hsvDown = function(e) { // mouseDown callback
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target === hsv_barcursor) currentTarget = e.target.parentNode;
    else if (e.target === hsv_barCursors) currentTarget = e.target;
    else return;

    startPoint = getOrigin(currentTarget);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', hsvMove);
    hsvMove(e);
    startRender();
  },
  hsvMove = function(e) { // mouseMove callback
    myColor.setColor({
      v: (hsv_barHeight - (e.clientY - startPoint.top)) / hsv_barHeight * 100
    }, 'hsv');
  };

// Initial Rendering
doRender(myColor.colors);

// Adde Events To Objects
luminenceBarWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', hsvDown);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', hsvMove);
  stopRender();
});

function doRender(color) {
  hsv_barcursor.style.transform = 'translateY(' + (100 - color.RND.hsv.v) / 100 * (hsv_barHeight - cursorRadius) + 'px)';
  //hsv_barcursor.style.top = ((1 - color.hsv.v) * hsv_barHeight) + 'px';
}

var renderTimer,
  startRender = function(oneTime) {
    renderTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
      doRender(myColor.colors);
    }, 13); // 1000 / 60); // ~16.666 -> 60Hz or 60fps
  },
  stopRender = function() {
    window.clearInterval(renderTimer);
  };

function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
}
#bar-bg {
  width: 15px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
#hsv-barcursors {
  position: absolute;
  right: -7.5px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 0;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#hsv-barcursor {
  position: absolute;
  right: 7.5px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/PitPik/colorPicker/master/colors.js"></script>

<div id="luminenceBarWrapper">
  <div id="bar-bg"></div>
  <div id="hsv-barcursors" id="hsv_cursors">
    <div id="hsv-barcursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation and the correct formula! Can you please show how to do it in percentage?

Comment: You can't do it in % [`translateY(t)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) `t` value is a [<length>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: Thanks! Also, how would I get the cursor to go halfway past the top and bottom border? (Right now, the cursor stops before it hits the top, but goes past the bottom.)